# How to fix 'Cannot find module vue-cli-service.js'?

Tags: vue.js, npm, installation

I'm setting up a new Vue project and when I'm running the command `npm run serve` into CMD, the following error appears:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Bram Wicherink\@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! real-world-vue@0.1.0 serve: 'vue-cli-service serve'
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the real-world-vue@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Bram Wicherink\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-13T14_03_01_676Z-debug.log
```

What do I have to do?

I have read the logs, I uninstalled and reinstalled NPM, Vue, Node.js and read some background information on Google, but nothing worked.

Comment: Run `npm install` before running `npm run serve`

Comment: Then I get the same error, after running `npm install` before that command.

Comment: Can you try to run `npm i @vue/cli-service`?

Comment: Unfortuantely it keeps saying that the module/service cannot be found, after multple times reinstalling NPM and the VUE Package...

Comment: One thing you can try is delete your `node_modules` folder and then run `npm install` again.

Comment: I tried, for two times, but it keeps saying the same error message. A little frustrating... :(

Comment: At the bottom of the error message you provided there is a reference to a log file. You can see if this gives you any usable hints or you can add it to your question so we can take a look at it.

Comment: It works again! I had to install npm via cmd ('npm install') two times again and strangely it did work? Thanks!

Comment: I run into the same problem. npm install and npm update did not work, but npm i @vue/cli-service worked fine. The problem appeared during writing code when I did not change any node_modules.

Answer (score 16):

In my case (Windows), the `node_modules\.bin\vue-cli-service.cmd` was failing because one of my parent folders had an ampersand character which breaks `%~dp0`

Comment: you are a god , been stucked from last 2 hrs , installing uninstalling npm , vue , then deleting node modules folder etc. Thanks mate

Comment: and what did you do to fix it? Rename the folder?

Comment: @marts This was a long time ago but from memory yes - that's the simplest fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Been stuck with this for a moment

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

Removing `&` from any of the folder's name or sub-folders inside which your project lies will resolve the issue.

**Explanation**

The `&` symbol in any of the folders or ancestor/parent folder's name inside which your project lies will initiate a vue-cli execution issue since `&` is a special character.

The %~dp0 (that’s a zero) variable when referenced within a Windows batch file will expand to the drive letter and path of that batch file.

The variables %0-%9 refer to the command line parameters of the batch file. %1-%9 refer to command-line arguments after the batch file name. %0 refers to the batch file itself.

**If you follow the percent character (`%`) with a tilde character (`~`), you can insert a modifier(s) before the parameter number to alter the way the variable is expanded. The `d` modifier expands to the drive letter and the `p` modifier expands to the path of the parameter.**

Example: Let’s say you have a directory on `C:` called bat_files, and in that directory is a file called `example.bat`. In this case, `%~dp0` (combining the `d` and `p` modifiers) will expand to `C:\bat_files\.`

Answer (score 1):

I had a `clean_bins.cmd` script run in my project which searches for all `/bin/` folders and removes it. After I run that script I had the same problem with `vue`.

To solve the issue just clean the `/node_modules/` folder and run `npm install`.

Comment: Looks like my `clean_bins.cmd` batch accidentally removed some `/bin/` folder in `/node_modules/`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just from my experience concerning this issue using multiple disks on a windows 10 development environment:
I have a work machine using multiple hard-drives: one split for the OS and another for file storage. The vue-cli install by following(droning off) the docs by default installed to my primary disk (C:), however attempting to configure -of which was successful- but running from the secondary disk (D:) resulted in the same error. Running vue-cli commands to create and serve the vue js app (the crux of the issue here) on the primary disk (C:) resolved this issue for me.

Please note: this is not an intact solution but rather observation from my end, even if it may sound trivial.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Kind of annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I had an ampersand character in my parent folder, I took 2 hours to try almost everything...
Just delete the "&" and then worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).