# cannot start vue project. shows error on running npm run serve

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I am using windows 10. my node version is 17.1.0,
npm version = 8.1.3,
vue cli version = 4.5.15, npm path is added to system environment. I started a vue project with vue create myapp. then chose default vue 2.0 with babel.js and eslint. after vue project setup when I cd into myapp folder and run npm run serve it shows the following error.

```
'Machine' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'G:\Project\Mevn Stack Projects\@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v17.1.0
```

What is this Machine. and how do I fix it. I tried looking in the internet haven't found any fix

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65352054/909973 Maybe?

Comment: Thank you, I found the fix in that forum "In my case (Windows), the node_modules\.bin\vue-cli-service.cmd was failing because one of my parent folders had an ampersand character which breaks %~dp0". I changed my folder name it seems special character caused this issue in the folder name